# External monitor resolution on Macbook Pro is not permanent, reverts to original when lightdm is restarted

Tags: display, greeter, macbook, resolution

I can set up a screen resolution on both the laptop screen and the external monitor using `xrandr` and everything works fine, but my displays go back to normal when I restart lightdm. How can I make the changes permanent? I tried going through the `monitors.xml` file, but it isn't being updated. The Displays item in system settings [isn't of much use...](http://tinyimg.io/i/HPQ24Uc.png)

Answer (score 1):

I had pretty much the same problem with display on an external monitor - display was fitted badly; I hardly could see wingpanel or plank.

I solved it with changing config file in `/boot/` directory.

In this file you need to find `disable_overscan` and change it's value to 1.
Then a bit further down you'll find

```
overscan_bottom=48
overscan_left=48
overscan_right=48
overscan_top=48
```

you can change these values to fit your display into monitor.

Then save it  and restart computer. It should be fine after few times. :)

Comment: Overscan is such a legacy curse! Some systems can't enable / disable it, and some monitors can't enable / disable it. And it isn't even really relevant anymore - so I wish they'd just burn it completely and stop building devices that ever use it!